# NTFS Partition input/output after using Testdisk

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs

I used testdisk to recover my partition. But after a successful recovery it prompted to restart the computer which I did. But then after restarting the NTFS partition has input/output errors. I can access some of the folders and file but others disappeared. I was given the option of NTFSFIX but it failed. It gives me the message below:

```
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking file system overflow... FAILED
Error: Failed to fix the alternate boot sector
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the reasons we had to recover a partition it is expected that Testdisk will not recover all of it. We will not be able to revive those parts of the drive which have been overwritten or are damaged otherwise.

Therefore Testdisk is extremely helpful in recovering those data that are still complete but it may not be able to restore the drive to it's original state if anything was written to it. This is where restoring a backup is the only means we have.

What should  be done now is to backup all important data to an external drive, repartition and format the drive, and then restore the backup. **Make sure the backup is complete before you wipe the drive holding your recovered data**.

In case we are faced with repeated I/O errors on that drive this may indicate a failing disk. Read the output of S.M.A.R.T. data for that drive for more information regarding this. It is then even more important to **immediately make a backup of your data**, as this drive may fail completely any time and therefore needs to be replaced.